# Is it possible to call a json function in the submit function?

Tags: jquery, json

The following code will successfully capture a clients ip address

```
var clientIP;
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
function (data) {
    clientIP = data.ip;
});

$("form").submit(function () {
alert(clientIP);
});
```

However this captures the ip address when the form loads.  Is it possible to refactor this so that the JSON function is called only when the user presses sumbit?  eg.

```
$("form").submit(function () {
      var clientIP = <somehow call getJSON function to get client ip>;
alert(clientIP);
});
```

Comment: What about var `clientIP = $.getJson...` Then access it with `clientIP.ip` or something like that? Not sure that would work though...

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for response:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
        function (data) {
            var clientIP = data.ip;
            alert(clientIP);
       });
       // prevent form submission
        return false;
});
```

Comment: If you don't prevent form submission, you more than likely won't get the alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clientIP;

function getIP(form) {
  $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
  function (data) {
    clientIP = data.ip;
    alert(clientIP);
  });
}


$("form").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default submission
  getIP(this);
});
```

#### Note

I passed the form to `getIP()`, so that you can submit the form within that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var clientIP; // declare it global otherwise you wont be able to use it from outside.
    $("form").submit(function () {
       $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
        function (data) {
            clientIP = data.ip;
       });
    return false; // return false so the form doesnt actually submit
    });
```